# Add functionality to existing DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridviews all throughout my WinForms application.

I want to be able to add functionality to all my datagridview with having to write code on each form. One method / event in one place added to all existing grids.

I want to be able to right click and have a contextmenu popup which allows a generic menu to appear which has standard export options.

I understand that I can add functionality using extension methods, but I do not believe this is the right approach for this situation.

I would like if I did not have to derive a new class from the datagridview class and add my functionality to the derived class, as I will then have to change all my dgv's to the derived dgv class.

Can I add or extend the existing datagridview class and add a global generic method and events to achieve the generic popup menu

Hope this make sense....

Comment: A derived class is the appropriate solution. Changing all your DataGridViews to use the new class is trivially accomplished with a search-and-replace.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to derive your own DGV class then you can create a **helper class**, which can do all the stuff you want it to.

You will have to **register** each DGV to it though - somehow there must be the connection to the extended functionality after all.. The registration can be automated in the Forms' constructors.

In its `registerDGV(DataGridview DGV)` method the helper class will subscribe to all the DGV's events you want to and do all the decorating you need.

This is just a tiny eample:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DGVhelper.registerDGV(dataGridView1);
}

DGVhelperClass DGVhelper= new DGVhelperClass ();


class DGVhelperClass 
{
    public void registerDGV(DataGridView DGV)
    {
        DGV.MouseDown += DGV_MouseDown;
        //...
        DGV.BackgroundColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        //..
    }

    void DGV_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) MessageBox.Show("just", "for show");
    }

}
```

You may want to make the helper class `static` if it needs no state information.